# Programmatically reuse layout with data binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have an xml layout consisting of textviews and an imageview showing User Profile and Location which I am getting from firebase (max 10). My main activity has a world map (fictional) as background. I am able to inflate the layout multiple times depending upon the number of users online with absolute positioning across the world map with data binding, however, all the layouts get added again after each update/add/remove change in the LiveData users list. How do I compare and ensure only changed  views get updated?

In other words, I want recyclerview like functionality (binding a list of data to a list of similar views) but for views with absolute positioning instead of linear or grid.

Following is my attempt. (Unnecessary code removed for brevity)

activity_main.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="userVM"
            type="com.xxx.xxx.viewmodels.UserViewModel"/>
    </data>
...
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        users="@{userVM}">
    </RelativeLayout>
...
```

MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
...
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    userViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, UserFactory(UserRepository()))[UserViewModel::class.java]
    binding.userVM = userViewModel
}
...
```

UserViewModel.kt

```kotlin
...
fun getUsers(): LiveData<List<User>>{
    return repository.getUsers()
}

fun selectUser(id: String){
    repository.selectUser(id)
...
```

BindingAdapter.kt

```kotlin
@BindingAdapter("users")
fun RelativeLayout.updateUsers(userVM: UserViewModel) {
    this.removeAllViews()
    val inflater = this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    for(user in userVM.getUsers()) {
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ViewUserBinding>(
            inflater,
            R.layout.view_user,
            this,
            false)
        binding.user = user
        binding.userVM = userVM
        val view = binding.root as ConstraintLayout
        this.addView(view, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50).apply {
            leftMargin = user.geo.x
            topMargin = user.geo.y
        })
    }
}
```

view_user.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.xxx.xxx.models.User" />
        <variable
            name="userVM"
            type="com.xxx.xxx.viewmodels.UserViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:onClick="@{() -> userVM.selectUser(user.id)}">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        userImage="@{user.image}"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
...
```

Please advise how to efficiently perform changes in UI depending on changes in LiveData of users

Comment: What does the source of data look like and what have you tried?

Comment: Fairly simple data class with user name, profile photo, geo location coordinates and online status. I haven't tried databinding since I am not sure how do I go about it. I am not looking for code, just the concept will suffice

Comment: How many views/"profiles" do you plan to have there?

Comment: 10 or less so I don't really need the 'recycling' feature

Answer (score 0):

The source of the data in the `DataBinding` has to be `LiveData` if you want them to be updated.

This will never get called twice.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    users="@{userVM}">
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can create multi-parameter bindings and if one of the parameter is LiveData it will update with the change.

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"viewModel", "users"}, requiredAll = true)
```

and then:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    users="@{userVM, userVM.getUsers()}">
</RelativeLayout>
```

but this will only introduce another problem. If you want the User view to be updated, the binding will again need `LiveData` source.

Your next problem is going to be passing `LiveData` to the user view binding.

```
<data>
    <import type="com.xxx.xxx.models.User" />
    <variable
        name="userId"
        type="String" />
    <variable
        name="user"
        type="androidx.lifecycle.LiveData&lt;User>" />
    <variable
        name="userVM"
        type="com.xxx.xxx.viewmodels.UserViewModel" />
</data>
```

and then populate it when inflating the view

```
    ...
    binding.userId = user.id
    binding.user = userVM.getUserLiveData(user.id)
    binding.userVM = userVM
    ...
```

With ALL of that said. You basically want `RecyclerView`, all of the above feels like a pretty big hack and misuse of things available but it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out. Do you know of an alternative way to achieve what I need i.e. recyclerview with absolute layout of items and no scrolling requirement, which is not a misuse?

Comment: If everything is going to be static? I would probably add all views in XML and enable/disable them based on how many I would need. That way you would avoid all of the BindingAdapter ugliness. Though 10 items seems like a lot for non-scrollable content, or do you mean scrollview?

Comment: No, data is not static and will change frequently and so will the position of each user items across the screen. Are you suggesting not to use data binding? Will the 'ugliness' impact the performance of the app or will it only complicate the code? I can work with the latter. I meant scrollview. I referred this article for hints https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-data-binding-list-tricks-ef3d5630555e.

Comment: How frequently?

Comment: Almost every minute. I have implemented your idea but how do I ensure my views (users) are updated efficiently similar to recyclerview? Currently, any change in livedata is causing views to be removed and added again. How do I use a feature like DiffUtil here to compare and update only changed views?